# android 7.0 write on sdCard error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/Cindy/KWMusic (No such file or directory)

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // got permission。
                //在本地创建文件
                File dir = new File(DOWNLOAD_PATH);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdir();
                    Log.i("test", "start " + dir + "");
                }
                Log.i("test", dir.getName() + "");
                File file = new File(dir, "KWMusic");
                Log.i("test file", file.getName() + "");
                PackageManager pm  = getPackageManager();
                Log.i("test PackageManagerInfo", pm.toString() );

                final ProviderInfo info = pm
                        .resolveContentProvider(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".cindy", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

                Log.i("test ProviderInfo", info.authority + "");

                Uri imageUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.getApplicationContext()
                        ,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".cindy", file);//这里进行替换uri的获得方式
                Log.i("test imageUri", imageUri + "");
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                } catch (IOException E) {
                    E.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("test", "文件没有创建");
                }
            } else {
                // did not have permission
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

/*log*/

```
04-11 14:43:03.373 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo I/test: start /data/Cindy
04-11 14:43:03.373 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo I/test: Cindy
04-11 14:43:03.373 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo I/test file: KWMusic
04-11 14:43:03.373 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo I/test PackageManagerInfo: android.app.ApplicationPackageManager@df00c90
04-11 14:43:03.374 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo I/test ProviderInfo: com.example.cindy.downloaddemo.cindy
04-11 14:43:03.375 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo I/test imageUri: content://com.example.cindy.downloaddemo.cindy/root/data/Cindy/KWMusic
04-11 14:43:03.375 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/Cindy/KWMusic (No such file or directory)
04-11 14:43:03.375 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
04-11 14:43:03.375 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
04-11 14:43:03.375 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at com.example.cindy.downloaddemo.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:238)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7345)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7197)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4280)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4327)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1624)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
04-11 14:43:03.376 12472-12472/com.example.cindy.downloaddemo I/test: 文件没有创建
```

Answer (score 0):

Try be replacing your code

```
File dir = new File(DOWNLOAD_PATH);
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdir();
    Log.i("test", "start " + dir + "");
}
```

With

```
File dir = new File(DOWNLOAD_PATH);
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdir(); // Here is difference
    Log.i("test", "start " + dir + "");
}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two code parts.

Comment: The only difference is the comment, stating there is [not] a difference!

Comment: OP is already doing this? What is the difference with the answer you provided?